# Javascript automation anywhere extracting information problem

Tags: javascript, html, automation, automationanywhere

I'm trying to figure out how to write this. I want this bot to be able to refresh the page, get an array of MUI Grid items, check rule if there are any MUI Grid items that have specified text in HTML InnerText table, if there are, then open them with Click action in another tab (Google Chrome).

I tried searching for those items by

```
var all=document.getElementsByClassName('MuiGrid-container');

for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){
 return all[i].innerHTML;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I tried also changing class name to "MuiButtonBase-root MuiCardActionArea-root" as in that website it's source code for that particular box is

```
<a class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiCardActionArea-root"
```

but that seems to fail as well. I did not get an array. I'm a beginner and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please explain more of problem ? if the problem is related to the pure javascript part, or to the library, if it is related to the pure js part, I am ready to answer, but when you give more detailed problem explaining

Comment: Are the elements present in the DOM when your JS is called?